# Is there difference in the laws for declaring jewellary that we wear vs that which we keep in carry on?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, gcc

It is a common phenomena for Indians travelling from GCC to back, to carry jewellary by wearing. I always understood it as simply done for status or maybe even aesthetics.

However, recently when I was talking to a friend, he told there is a difference in laws regarding declaration and taxation when we keep the jewellary in the carry on / lugage vs when we wear it and go.

Is this really true?

I tried searching online and I could only find generic statements like there are laws and it varies depending on country.

Comment: This would definitely be country-specific, so you would need to tell us which country you are interested in (there are definitely countries where this is not true at all, though).

Comment: GCC to India @jcaron it's also tagged so

Comment: Carry on vs hold luggage is irrelevant. What matters is whether the items meet the duty free conditions. Not declaring items above the limit is an offence no matter how it is carried https://www.nriguides.com/indian-customs-gold-duty-allowance-rules/

Comment: Usually the only thing that matters is whether you can prove that you originally bought the jewelry in India or had previously imported it. That is, you brought it with you the last time you left India.

Comment: I assume the idea is that if you're wearing it, then customs people will think it's personal jewellery you took with you, rather than stuff you are importing and which duty is due on. But customs people aren't stupid.